# Does PHP not optimize in this way? Is it top-down interpreted language?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, performance-testing

I'm trying to figure out why my pages are taking so long to load. I have a page with like 30 calls to `get_template_directory_uri()` and the implementation of that function makes calls to the database, but the value returned by the function is the same for the entirety of my page generation. Therefore I should probably do something like

```
$tduri = get_template_directory_uri();
```

and use `$tduri` as needed, at least as a good practice, but is this totally necessary or would the value of `get_template_directory_uri()` have been cached anyways?

Comment: The value of a function call isn't cached, unless your code explicitly caches it..... we can't guess why you're getting the same result every time you call `get_template_directory_uri()` because we can't see the code.... but as there doesn't look like anything in the call to tell it to do anything different on subsequent calls (no arguments or anything), my guess would be that it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do

Comment: Function calls are not cached.  PHP doesn't know that the return value won't change each time it's called.  Saving that into a variable should help speed things up.

Comment: Doing 30 identical database calls will always be slower than doing one. PHP  does not cache anything unless you tell it to. If the database calls are all the same then you should just call it once and save the result in a variable.

Comment: @MarkBaker It's expected behavior here for me to get the same value from every call. I'm asking whether it's worthwhile to cache that value.

Comment: Asking a "language" without [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) constraints to cache the result of an arbitrary function automagically is asking a lot; but that function also consuming data from an external source like e.g. a database _miiiiiight_ be stretching it a little. No, php doesn't do that - you have to do that yourself. And given your description you probably should.

Comment: Database access is a big overhead for any script, and if you are simply executing exactly the same query 30 times during the course of execution, then "yes", it is sensible to cache that result and eliminate 29 expensive database calls

Comment: A much more relevant issue here is caching and efficiency of the *MySQL*, rather than the PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not cache return values of functions by itself. In your case the function is making a call to an external database, so how could PHP even know if the result was the same or different each time the function was called?

Also consider that any call to an external system is highly likely to be slower than storing a variable within a PHP script.

So yes, absolutely, cache the return value somewhere suitable and always test whether it makes a noticeable improvement, sometimes the results can be suprising. There are many good ways to profile PHP,  [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) is very quick for ad-hoc testing without requiring additional set-up. Search for 'PHP profiling' to get the more powerful tools.